# Missing Host header in HTTP requests from the requests Python library

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-headers

Where is the [HTTP/1.1 mandatory Host header field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4) in HTTP request messages generated by the `requests` Python library?

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/")
print(response.request.headers)
```

Output:

> {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

Comment: use https://httpbin.org/get to get all headers which server gets.  `requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get")` `print(response.content)` It seems it sends `Host` but it doesn't show it later. If you set wrong `Host` in `get(..., headers={'Host':'example.com'})` then it still works correctly - so this field seems not so mandatory - and then it shows this header in `response.request.headers`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `HOST` header is not being added to the request by `requests` by default. If it is not explicitly added then the decision is delegated to the underlying `http` module.

See this section of [`http/client.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/http/client.py#L1104):

(if `'Host'` header is explicitly provided in `requests.get` then `skip_host` is `True`)

```
    if self._http_vsn == 11:
        # Issue some standard headers for better HTTP/1.1 compliance

        if not skip_host:
            # this header is issued *only* for HTTP/1.1
            # connections. more specifically, this means it is
            # only issued when the client uses the new
            # HTTPConnection() class. backwards-compat clients
            # will be using HTTP/1.0 and those clients may be
            # issuing this header themselves. we should NOT issue
            # it twice; some web servers (such as Apache) barf
            # when they see two Host: headers

            # If we need a non-standard port,include it in the
            # header.  If the request is going through a proxy,
            # but the host of the actual URL, not the host of the
            # proxy.

            netloc = ''
            if url.startswith('http'):
                nil, netloc, nil, nil, nil = urlsplit(url)

            if netloc:
                try:
                    netloc_enc = netloc.encode("ascii")
                except UnicodeEncodeError:
                    netloc_enc = netloc.encode("idna")
                self.putheader('Host', netloc_enc)
            else:
                if self._tunnel_host:
                    host = self._tunnel_host
                    port = self._tunnel_port
                else:
                    host = self.host
                    port = self.port

                try:
                    host_enc = host.encode("ascii")
                except UnicodeEncodeError:
                    host_enc = host.encode("idna")

                # As per RFC 273, IPv6 address should be wrapped with []
                # when used as Host header

                if host.find(':') >= 0:
                    host_enc = b'[' + host_enc + b']'

                if port == self.default_port:
                    self.putheader('Host', host_enc)
                else:
                    host_enc = host_enc.decode("ascii")
                    self.putheader('Host', "%s:%s" % (host_enc, port))
```

As a result we do not see the `'Host'` header when inspecting the headers that `requests` sent to the server.

If we send a request to http://httpbin/get and print the response we can see the `Host` header was indeed sent.

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get")
print('Response from httpbin/get')
print(response.json())
print()
print('response.request.headers')
print(response.request.headers)
```

Outputs

```
Response from httpbin/get
{'args': {}, 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.20.0'},
 'origin': 'XXXXXX', 'url': 'https://httpbin.org/get'}

response.request.headers
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.20.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```